# Porter stemming of 'ion-er' words

Tags: r, nlp, porter-stemmer, snowball-stemmer

I'm coding in R and lemmatizing some text about air-conditioning. I use the Snowball stemming library `SnowballC::wordStem()`, which implements the Porter Stemming Algorithm.  I was surprised by this result:

```
library(SnowballC)
library(tidyverse)
c("conditioner", "conditioning", "condition") %>% SnowballC::wordStem()
[1] "condition" "condit"    "condit"
```

Usually, the results of Porter-stemming can't be further stemmed.  But here, *conditioner* > *condition* while *condition* still goes to *condit*.  Is this a bug? or am I misunderstanding the Porter Stemmer?

The pattern holds for other '-ioner' words like *conventioner, petitioner, revisioner*, but not for
'evaluate' -

```
c("evaluate", "evaluation", "evaluating", "evaluator") %>% SnowballC::wordStem()
[1] "evalu" "evalu" "evalu" "evalu"
```

The pattern isn't unique to the R SnowballC library; I found online stemmers for Python NLTK and one in C, and they show the same pattern.

So - Is this a bug?  And is there a straightforward workaround?

Comment: To clarify:
`R > packageVersion("SnowballC") ->
[1] ‘0.7.0’`